# Best ways to add indices to an existing Elasticsearch instance

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

whats the best way to move over an index from one server to another, which already has its own index that is unrelated to the first server ?

basically the scenario is, 
I have an index on server-1, which is used by website-1, and due to server cost, i want to move website-2 that will use its own ES index from server-2 on server-1.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: Are you planning to move one or more index/indices from one cluster to another? if Yes then As @Andrei's Stefan refered the `snapshot` & `restore` is the best one to move an index from one cluster to another